# What does the following recurrence formula represent

Tags: algorithms

I know that :

$T(n,k)=T(n−1,k−1)+T(n−1,k)$ is the Pascal triangle.

But what is this then:

$T(n,k)=T(n−1,k−1)+T(n,k-1)$

Is there any name for it? I am trying to learn about it's time complexity etc, but I can't find anything online.

Comment: What is the time complexity of a recurrence? Time complexity is usually associated with algorithms: it describes the asymptotic rate of growth of their running time.

Comment: You might find it useful to know about https://oeis.org/

Comment: Let $T'(n,m):=T(m,n)$. Rewrite the second recurrence.

Answer (score 3):

The second recurrence is ALSO Pascal's Triangle (interchange n and k).